# Issues with CuteSpotify in Ubuntu Phone

Tags: sound, ubuntu-touch, phone, spotify

I have recently bought an Ubuntu Phone (I am one of the few lucky ones with a BQ 4.5 Ubuntu editon) and I am finding some issues when using Spotify's unoficial client, Cutespotify.

First of all, when Cutespotify is playing, and the screen goes for ivernation, the player stops about after a minute. The same thing happens when I open any other app. So I can't listen to my spotify account and use my phone at the same time, and neither can I simply leave the phone play.

I decided to change the baterry settings not to go on ivernation ever whenever I use CuteSpotify, but even then I'm having issues, because if I low the volume, it works, but it goes back loud on every new song.

So, I'm not sure there will be anyone there that can help me. I will appreciate if someone can tell me at least who to ask.

Comment: Having the same issues, concerning the player stopping after a minute, I guess this is a 'core' problem (although I'm not sure) and should best be logged on the ubuntu phone bug list. The sound all of a sudden going back too loud according to me has something to do with the cute spotify app as well, I would log it there, but I'm not sure which source branch is installed on the phone (there seem to be two of them, both tailored for sailfish, so not very clear). 
And indeed : http://blog.mikeasoft.com/2013/11/12/cutespotify-for-ubuntu-touch/

Comment: I am having the same issue, the experience is a bit rough. It is pretty hard to determine whose responsibilities those bugs are. About this one for instance Popey told me it was because of a third party library that does not integrate with the playback system (https://twitter.com/popey/status/580041736682119171). It's hard to blame the dev of the soft for that. Should it be the platform? Not sure either. I wish we had a common place to talk about that. Is askubuntu the right place?